# Dart/Flutter convert a fraction string to a double

Tags: flutter, dart, double, dart-null-safety

If I have a fraction double stored as a string i.e., "16/9", "16 / 9", "9/16", "9 / 16", etc., how can I convert it to a double? Or should I store those differently in order to convert them to doubles to be used as aspectRatio settings? Code example:

```
String aspectRatio = "16/9";
OR String aspectRatio = "16 / 9";
  
final aspectRatioDouble = double.parse(aspectRatio);
print(aspectRatioDouble); 
/// Throws "Uncaught Error: FormatException: Invalid double 16/9"

final aspectRatioDoubleTry = double.tryParse(aspectRatio);
print(aspectRatioDoubleTry); 
/// Prints null
```

Answer (score 2):

The [function_tree](https://pub.dev/packages/function_tree) is a useful package for parsing mathematical expressions like yours which are presented as `String` directly, sample of what it can do:

```
'16 / 9'.interpret(); // 1.77
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `.split` method on Strings to split them by a specific character. For example we have a String like `String unusualNumber = "Number=22"`, we can call `unusualNumber.split['='].last` to extract the number which in our case is `22` from it.

Solution for your code:

```dart
String aspectRatio = "16/9";
OR String aspectRatio = "16 / 9";

final List<String> split = aspectRatio.split("/");
final double actualRatio = double.parse(aspectRatio.first) / double.parse(aspectRatio.last);
```

`actualRatio` will be 16 / 9 as a double.
Read more about `split` method:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/split.html

Answer (score 0):

It is better to store these in the form of two separate variables i.e., `height` and `width`.
That gives you the flexibility to combine these as a `String` like "16/9" or "16:9" or represent as a `double` like "1.77".